# How to use babel-cli directory paths?

Tags: babeljs, babel-cli

**EDIT: Answered, below.**

**Also: If you are reading this you are probably new to web dev and you should consider using webpack for this instead of babel alone**

I have what seems like a very simple problem but I can't solve it.

I have a directory structure

```
Project
 |
 +-- scripts
    |
    |
    +-- src / src.js
    |
    |
    +-- compiled / compiled.js
```

And I have been trying to get the following command to work when my terminal is located in the **scripts** folder.

```
C:\Users\me\JavaScriptProjects\survey\scripts>npx babel ./src/src.js --out-file ./compiled/compiled.js presets=env,react --watch
```

But it simply keeps returning:

C:\Users\me\JavaScriptProjects\survey\scripts>npx babel ./src/src.js --out-file ./compiled/compiled.js presets=env,react --watch
presets=env,react **doesn't exist**

I have tried permutations of removing the `./`, replacing it with only `/`, going into src dir and replacing `src/src.js` with `src.js` and then doing `../compiled/compiled.js` and many other permutations, but it just keeps saying it doesn't exist.

Even if I add both files to the same directory it's giving the same error.

Most annoying part is it was working fine yesterday.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

The following has worked from within the src dir after trying for around an hour. I don't know what I've done differently, would love it if someone can point it out.

Thanks.

```
C:\Users\me\JavaScriptProjects\survey\scripts\src>npx babel src.js --out-file=../compiled/compiled.js --presets=env,react --watch
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you have a babel.config.json file in the \scripts\src folder and that if you move to the \scripts folder to run npx, then it can't see the config file and so doesn't see react.

```
Project
 |
 +-- scripts
    |
    +-- src / src.js
    +-- src / babel.config.json
    |
    +-- compiled / compiled.js
```